# Pairwise post-hoc test for 60 factor levels with multcomp's glht()

Tags: r, post-hoc

I am a molecular biologist, and i have tried 60 different PCR-Primers (for the record, only the forward primer was changed), and i want to compute if the selection of the forward primer has impact on the outcome (here: "reads"). I have 6 replicates for each primer.

I do

```
library(multcomp)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(6*60,mean=1000000,sd=100000), 6, 60)) 
data <- melt(data)

mod <- aov(value~variable, data=data)
res <- glht(mod, mcp(variable="Tukey"))
summary(res)
```

and i get

```
Error in mvt(lower = carg$lower, upper = carg$upper, df = df, corr = carg$corr,  : 
  only dimensions 1 <= n <= 1000 allowed
```

I strongly believe that the number of factors involved are not allowed. Is this a mathematical or a performance limitations?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes. But thats a software limitation, correct? Mathematically, that should be doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is just a software limitation. I edited the portion of the code that stops it from running if >1000 and it runs into problems later down, in the source code around the part that causes this error there is notation that it is a yet to be fixed bug.

I don't know what about the code is the problem but there doesn't appear to be an easy work around since the function just can't handle it.

Comment: @rvl can you clarify? the software sets the limit at 1000, so is there a mathematical reason why 999 makes complete sound statistical sense and 1000 is unresaonable?